# iOS - embed iAd into UIWebView as part of content

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, iad

I'm creating my iOS application's interface with HTML/CSS/JavaScript inside UIWebView. I wold like to display iAd as part of news feed inside my app.
I don't want to place iAd above or below UIWebView as one may recommend.
Instead I want iAd to scroll with UIWebView content.

Is there any trick to embed iAd into UIWebView or to make iAd behave like it is embedded inside UIWebViews content?

Answer (score 0):

If displaying the iAd at the same level than the `UIWebView` or the `UIWebView`'s content view is not an option (i.e. on top, above, below the webview or its content), then I believe there is no a proper solution to your question.

The [`ADBannerView`](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fprerelease%2Fios%2Fdocumentation%2FUserExperience%2FReference%2FADBannerView_Ref%2Findex.html&ei=_akaVYalIJfYaq6agcgC&usg=AFQjCNG3ASykpWNYZoedcs7cf-mzn3PExg&bvm=bv.89381419,d.d2s) is just a native view (inherits from `UIView`, as the `UIWebView`) acting as **a container for the iAd** to be displayed. Unfortunately, **you can control the container, but not the content** (the ad itself). Therefore, there is no way I can think of for you to get the content and inject it to your `UIWebview`'s web content.

You might want to **consider other ad providers** that support displaying ads in web content.

Comment: I understand, that extracting content (or even html) from ADBannerView end injecting it into my own UIWebView is not permitted. Actually I'm looking for someone who has positive experience in embedding ADBannerView inside UIWebView's scrollview at some point where special HTML anchor appears